# NSSM Powershell Script Windows 2012 Server. Error creating service

Tags: powershell, nssm

I have a powershell script to create service that works on my local Windows 10 PC. Below works correctly.

```
$nssm = (Get-Command nssm).Source
$serviceName = 'ImageResize'
$powershell = (Get-Command powershell).Source
$scriptPath = 'C:\ImageTest\Scripts\current\ResizeImage.ps1'
$arguments = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File "{0}"' -f $scriptPath
& $nssm install $serviceName $powershell $arguments
& $nssm status $serviceName
Start-Service $serviceName
Get-Service $serviceName
```

When trying same script on windows 2012 server I get errors.  Transcript shows following:

```
The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
At line:10 char:3
+ & $nssm install $serviceName $powershell $arguments
+   ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression
```

I also found the following in the Event Viewer:

Application

```
Failed to start service imagetest.  Program C:\ImageResizeScript\ResizeImage.ps1 couldn't be launched. CreateProcess()` failed: imagetest is not a valid Win32 application.
```

System

```
The system cannot find the specified path
```

Comment: Do both `(Get-Command nssm).Source` and `Get-Command nssm` work correctly on the 2012 server?

Comment: I guess not.  Get-Command nssm works.  Thanks a lot...  What's the difference between the two?

Comment: You're probably seeing differences due to different PowerShell versions. Either adopt the script and simply get the path another way, or upgrade PowerShell to 5.1 on the server: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

Comment: Actually it seems Get-Command when forced to string as it probably is that might work as well, maybe that's what you meant, it works as is with just `Get-Command nssm`?

Comment: Yes, Worked as Get-Command nssm